# Amazon Echo - Alexa - ContextClient is null developing skill with Lambda in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing a new skill to Amazon Echo and I'm facing some problems when I need to get the clientContext to verify what is the Client ID of this Amazon Echo in the application.

Anyone know how it works correctly? Every time I receive `undefined` value in `context.clientContext`.

I made this process in Alexa developer panel:

1) Create a Skill as "Custom interaction Model"

2) Filled the Interaction Model correctly

3) Endpoint I linked with the Lambda Function

4) I've checked `Yes` to "Do you allow users to create an account or link to an existing account with you?" question.

In lambda function I made it:

1) Used example "Colors" of the Alexa in Lambda

2) In the first line, I put the log to verify what the information is arriving.

Like this:

```
console.log("event.session.application.applicationId=" + event.session.application.applicationId);
console.log('clientContext =', context.clientContext); 
console.log('context =', context);
```

The data is:

```
clientContext = undefined
```

> { callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: [Getter/Setter], done: [Function],
>   succeed: [Function], fail: [Function], logGroupName:
>   '/aws/lambda/color', logStreamName:
>   '2016/08/19/[$LATEST]7d66fec34f604692ad4c0bd1d138ae51', functionName:
>   'color', memoryLimitInMB: '128', functionVersion: '$LATEST',
>   getRemainingTimeInMillis: [Function], invokeid:
>   '14c606ef-6614-11e6-940d-cd0e175f3bda', awsRequestId:
>   '14c606ef-6614-11e6-940d-cd0e175f3bda', invokedFunctionArn:
>   'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:...........86:function:color' }

I read in the Lambda documentation that it is possible for this value to be `null`, but what is the reason for this value to be null?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why do you need to verify the client id? are you trying to verify who the linked user is?

Comment: Yes. to verify who is linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure out who the linked user is by using the OAuth token that your server returned to Amazon upon account linkage.

In a skill, that token is passed to you, if it exists, by amazon in the session. 
Eg. In a javascript Lambda: session.user.accessToken